Anime that had floating islands/biomes
I watched this anime around 2020 or 2022 and it had a protagonist that was able to activate these floating islands that were made by a woman professor who could see the future or went back in time. She knew that the protagonist will have multiple wives and made the robot girls guarding the place lewd.

TIL they made an anime of "In Another World With My Smartphone."
The woman professor from 5000 years ago is Professor Babylon, who foresaw the protagonist's (Mochizuki Tōuya) arrival as a proto-god.  Professor Babylon also foresaw that Tōuya would have nine wives.
The gynoids (surnamed Babylon) are each assigned to a different part of the floating island lair of Professor Babylon.  (Of course the island lair is also called Babylon...)
Tōuya needs to find all the nine pieces of Babylon and have each recognize him as the new owner (which Professor Babylon has foreseen and prepared for).  Note that the gynoids aren't lewd because of Tōuya, they're lewd because that's how Professor Babylon herself was.



